# generating RSA keys through the browser

Tags: certificates, web-browser, public-key-infrastructure, rsa

HTML5 has the  element that sends an SPKAC to the server (as I understand it).

But how do you do it in IE?

One CA's websites gives me the following prompt:

```
This Web site is attempting to perform a digital certificate operation on your behalf:

https://www.startssl.com/

You should only allow known Web sites to perform digital certificate operations on your behalf.
Do you want to allow this operation?
```

That's cool and all but how do they do it and how do I make it so a website of mine can generate private keys for people? [IE doesn't support the keygen element](http://html5.litten.com/html5-keygen-element-and-internet-explorer/).

Comment: related [Benefits and drawbacks of the keygen element](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/27955/396)

Comment: See also: [Can IE process the Keygen element like Chrome does](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/26148/396)

Comment: [Alternatives to Keygen](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/27961/396)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Internet Explorer, for this kind of job, you are supposed to use the [CertEnroll API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/certenroll-portal) (in pre-Vista Windows, this was called XEnroll); it can be [used from Javascript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alejacma/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-javascript). This implies Javascript to detect the type of browser.

Microsoft [says](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190282/en-us) that lack of support for `<keygen>` is "by design".

Comment: *by design* == it's not easy for us to add a meatball to our spaghetti

Answer (score 1):

When this question was asked in 2013, we did not have the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API), but now we do.  The SubtleCrypto.generateKey() function can be used to generate RSA key pairs on the client side, in javascript.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey for more info.